# Calculating gradient of a function for optimization

Tags: r, optimization, java, gradient

I need to optimize a function. This function is a likelihood function which takes a set of parameters (to be optimized) and calculates the likelihood (to be optimized) as a result.

```
b{} //utility function parameters (input)
d //data (input)
// calculate likelihood (operation)
exp(d*b)...
...
ll // likelihood (output)
```

I first wrote my likelihood function in **R** language and used **optim** as optimizer. This optim function takes an objective function and inputs but doesn't require a gradient function, it calls a C library in back-end but i couldn't find it's source code to explore how it works. (Probably it gives different values iteratively as input; not sure...)

Now i need to develop same function in java. For a similar optimization calculation, i decided to use [Weka optimization library](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Optimization.html) (or [Joptimizer](http://www.joptimizer.com/JOptimizer.html) which is so similar). These libraries optimization functions need "objective function"(my likelihood function) and "gradient function" (gradient of my likelihood function).

```
class MyOpt extends Optimization {
   // Provide the objective function **i have this**
   protected double objectiveFunction(double[] x) {
     // How to calculate your objective function...
     // ...
   }

   // Provide the first derivatives **i need this**
   protected double[] evaluateGradient(double[] x) {
     // How to calculate the gradient of the objective function...
     // ...
   }

   // If possible, provide the indexˆ{th} row of the Hessian matrix
   protected double[] evaluateHessian(double[] x, int index) {
     // How to calculate the indexˆth variable's second derivative
     // ...
   }
 }
```

I couldn't turn my objective function's (likelihood) code to a simple mathematical function to differentiate so i can't provide a gradient function. I would like to learn how to calculate derivative of a function which cannot be formulated mathematically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you may try to compute a derivative numerically, but that will drastically increase computation time.
You can read about gradient checking here [www.holehouse.org/mlclass](http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/09_Neural_Networks_Learning.html)

Comment: i think you're pointing "Gradient checking" part in targeted link for numerical derivative computation. I also thought to calculate for instant, it is the last option for me.

Comment: i mean, i thought to calculate derivative numerically but it is the last option for instance.

Comment: well, can you post your likelihood function? if it just contains a bunch of if-s, than same if-s should be in your derivative.

Answer (score 1):

@Yurii After a long way of research and unsatisfactory results from simplex method (Nelder Mead), i decided to write a small numeric gradient function as you mentioned (There is also *grad* function in *NumDeriv* package in *R*). I used **1e-4** as epsilon (like in *grad* function).

First i tested my numeric gradient function in *R*'s *optim* function. I called *optim* with and without grandient function and saw that there is negligible differences in calculated likelihood value and optimized parameters between two.

Further i will write a numeric gradient function in Java and continue to use **BFGS** method because it performs out (values and time) simplex method *Nelder Mead*. Also, there are many libraries ready to use/compare for BFGS and L-BFGS-B algorithms unlike Nelder-Mead; for which the only option is apache math3 library that i could have found.